# Angular Routing Failure - Modal Pop Up

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-routing

I'm working in Angular 8. I'm using NG-BOOTSTRAP for styling.

In several of my components I offer the ability to click a delete button on an item, this brings up a modal window with a YES or NO and when YES is clicked, the modal closes and the route appears to refresh, no actual browser refresh - this is what I want. The list is updated correctly and all seems fine. Then, when I try and click on any other route in my navbar they all fail and the page stays where it's at until I refresh the browser page - also, the link in the URL bar isn't updating, which I suspect is causing the pages not to be able to be routed to. Not sure why this behavior is happening. Frustrating too. Looking for some assistance if possible. Thanks.

```
THIS IS THE HTML TABLE

<tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let client of clients">
                <td>{{ client.name | titlecase }}</td>
                <td>{{ client.website }}</td>
                <td>{{ client.phone }}</td>
                <td>{{ client.address.street | titlecase }}, {{ client.address.city | titlecase }}
                  {{ client.address.state | uppercase }}
                  {{ client.address.zip }}</td>
                <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editClient(client._id)">
                    <fa-icon [icon]="faEdit"></fa-icon>
                  </button>
                  <button class="btn btn-danger ml-3" (click)="open(content, client)">
                    <fa-icon [icon]="faTrashAlt"></fa-icon>
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>

----- THIS IS THE MODAL TEMPLATE (SAME HTML PAGE)------

<!-- MODAL TEMPLATE -->
<ng-template #content let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Delete Client?</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <button class="btn btn-success mr-3" (click)="deleteClient(modalContent._id)">YES</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="modal.close('Close click')">NO</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>


----- THIS IS THE TS FILE -----

deleteClient(id) {
    this._clientService.deleteClient(id).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response['message']);

        // Close the modal window and reload the component
        this._modalService.dismissAll();
        this.reloadComponent();
      },
      error => console.log(error['message'])
    );
  }

  ///// MODAL FUNCTIONS
  open(content, client) {
    this.modalContent = client;
    this._modalService
      .open(content, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title' })
      .result.then(
        result => {
          this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
        },
        reason => {
          this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
        }
      );
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }

  ///// FUNCTION TO RELOAD PAGE AFTER DELETE /////
  reloadComponent() {
    this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
    this._router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
    this._router.navigate(['admin/clients']);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reloading the page you could re-execute the call that binds the results from the backend to your **clients** var. This is at least a nice separation of sources & routing and can avoid further complications.

Something like:

```
deleteClient(id) {
 this._clientService.deleteClient(id).subscribe(
  response => {
    console.log(response['message']);

    // Close the modal window and reload the component
    this._modalService.dismissAll();
    this.getClients();
  }, error => console.log(error['message'])
});

getClients() {
 this._clientService.getClients().subscribe(
  response => {
    this.clients = response.data;
  }, error => console.log(error['message'])
});
```

Comment: That worked great! Thanks so much. I don't know why I didn't think of it. Really appreciate the help!